# Switch between Workbooks, Loop through sheets and copy ranges

Tags: vba

I need help one last time, code below works fine; it copies values (A1) from sheets  that is in array to a new created sheet in org file. The last modyfication I want to make here, is that in this NOT_ORG file I want to copy range of values, rather than 1 value. This range always starts from A7, but the number of cols and rows might change. I want to copy this range dynamically and paste in in range(a1) in newly created sheet. I know that I should calculate lastRow & lastCol, but not sure where to put this code, and how to modify this last copy line to achieve this result.

Tagging @faneduru as he helped me initially.

```
Sub Test1()

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim WshtNames As Variant
  Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
  Dim WB1 As Workbook
  Dim WB2 As Workbook
  Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\NOT_ORG.xlsx")

  WshtNames = Array("2", "3")
  For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    WB1.Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
    WB2.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Range("A1").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
  Next WshtNameCrnt

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.
eM

Comment: When you say that the number of rows and columns may change, can you state, at least, if all columns have the same number of rows? And calculating the number of columns on the 7th row will it be relevant for all the range? I mean, no data in the other row on a column bigger than the one calculated on the seventh row. Then, do you need copying the format, too? Otherwise, using arrays, the code will become considerably faster..

Comment: Hey, yes, all columns has the same number of rows, its just "table" in a sense in one sheet I might have 10 columns and for each of the column we have 20 rows, in other sheet it might be different, for example 5 cols, 10 rows for each - but its consistent - basically, I want this macro to take same action as I would manually select (starting from A7 - ctrl +shift +rightarrow & downarrow. I dont need copying format, It's just about copying values

Comment: OK. I will post an answer. You forgot answer the question regarding the format...

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes sorry - formats are irrelevant - its just about copying values within this range

Comment: I posted an answer (using copy). I will post another piece of code using arrays and not using clipboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, WshtNames, WshtNameCrnt
  Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
  
  Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\NOT_ORG.xlsx")

  WshtNames = Array("2", "3")
  For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    WB1.Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
    Set ws = WB2.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    lastCol = ws.cells(7, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ws.Range(ws.Range("A" & 7), ws.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
  Next WshtNameCrnt
End Sub
```

And a faster version, using an array:

```
Sub Test1Array()
  Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, WshtNames, WshtNameCrnt
  Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arr
  
  Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\NOT_ORG.xlsx")

  WshtNames = Array("2", "3")
  For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    WB1.Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
    Set ws = WB2.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    lastCol = ws.cells(7, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr = ws.Range(ws.Range("A" & 7), ws.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).value
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr
  Next WshtNameCrnt
End Sub
```

Comment: @eM_Sk Edited the answer and place another version using an array. It should be faster (in case of big ranges, you can see the difference)...